# What is the error in this code? when I type it without the dimensions, it's ok, but after it the whole page dissapears

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I type it without the dimensions, it's ok, but after it the whole page dissapears, I don't really understand why?

```
$src = $row['product_image'];
echo "<td>" "<img src="$src"  height="30px" width="30px" >" "</td>";
```

Comment: $src = $row['product_image'];
                 echo "<td>" "<img src="$src"  height="30px" width="30px" >" "</td>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forcing a concatenated string without the concatenation character. You'll need to escape the quotes for the image dimensions:

```
echo "<td><img src=\"$src\" height=\"30px\" width=\"30px\" /></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

That second line has a number of issues. You have unescaped double quotes inside a double-quoted string, and appear to be trying to concatenate without using the concatenate operator.

Change your second line to this:

```
echo "<td><img src='$src' height='30px' width='30px'></td>";
```

This now has double quotes only at the beginning and end, with single quotes inside. The `$src` variable will be parsed and work properly since it is in a double-quoted string.

This may be some helpful reading: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this:

```
$src = $row['product_image'];
echo "<td><img src='$src'  height='30px' width='30px' ></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the concatenation operator `.` between the different strings, like this:

```
echo "<td>" . "<img src=" . $src . "  height='30px' width='30px' >" . "</td>";
```

You also had double quotes inside double quotes, which either needed to be escaped with `\` or replaced with single quotes (as I did above).

A better way of writing that would be like this:

```
echo '<td><img src="' . $src . '"  height="30px" width="30px" ></td>';
```